# ExpressJS controller not being called

Tags: node.js, express

I have a route that calls my controller and the controller does nothing but respond with a view. Nothing dynamic happening here. I am using Swig for my views. For some reason, my view is not getting refreshed with the new changes. it still shows me the old view. I have tried the following to no avail:

```
app.set('view cache', false);
// To disable Swig's cache, do the following:
swig.setDefaults({ cache: false });
app.disable('view cache');
app.set('etag', 'strong');
```

I have a `console.log` statement in my controller and it never seems to log anything out leading me to believe that that controller is never called. I do have a simple middleware that logs the path out before the routes are set up and I see the request for my route but the controller never gets called and an older version of the template view is served.

Am I missing something??

Update: Server controller code:

```
exports.index = function (req, res) {
    res.render('myapp', {});
};
```

Comment: Can you update your question with controller code?

Comment: It has nothing in it. I later added a console.log just to see if the request gets all the way to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

In order to check your code without node.js restart, consider to use **pm2** or **nodemon**

After installation of pm2:

```
pm2 start app.js --watch
```

PM2 automatically restarts your app when a file changes in the current directory or its subdirectories.

But my favorite choice is *nodemon*:

```
nodemon [your node app]
```